# Setting attributes on a html collection

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple to do list as a first project. I am trying to create a method that will grey out all the start/end times which have an earlier time than end time of an activity that the user has already inputted. This is to stop overlaps in the activities.

I have selected all the option tags from the DOM and turned this into an array. This allows me to use the For each method to loop over the array and they add the 'disable' attribute to each of the options. I keep getting the following error in the console: 'Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.'

I have a feeling there may be more issues with this code but this is what I am dealing with right now!

This is some of the HTML code just to give you an idea of the setup:

```
<select id="input_time" name="Time"  style="height:36px" required>
                    <option value="Start">Start</option>
                    <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
                    <option value="05:15">05:15</option>
                    <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
```

This is the relevant javascript:

```
 stopOverlap: function(endTime) {
                var optionsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
                var optionsArr = Array.from(optionsCollection)
                optionsArr.forEach(function(current) { 
                    if (current.textContent < endTime) {
                        current.setAttribute("disabled");

                    }

                })


                },
```

Comment: setAttribute requires 2 parameters. So where you have current.setAttribute("disabled"), just do current.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setAttribute requires 2 parameters. So where you have current.setAttribute("disabled"), just do current.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");

```
            optionsArr.forEach(function(current) { 
                if (current.textContent < endTime) {
                    current.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");

                }

            })
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I guess it was pretty self explanatory! Just wasn't sure what I was meant to put as the 2nd attribute.

Comment: @PaulBailey please click the green checkmark next to this answer to indicate that this answer has solved your problem

Comment: Ok all done. Will remember this for future posts. I wasn't aware this was the correct way to mark a correct answer. Thanks again

Comment: @PaulBailey Glad you got your problem solved, and thanks for clicking the answer